# Handle workaround for authenticated login popup using import.io

Tags: import.io

I have spent many hours trying to find a way to capture articles on http://www.law360.com. I have been able to create the bulk URLs I want to scrape, etc.: that works fine.
I am just running into a brick wall with the login. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try creating an Authenticated Extractor?